# Parse Unknown Length Text from file using Regular Expression REGEX

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to extract text from a text file but the length of the text to collect varies in length.  This is my first attemt at using RegEx and could use some sugestions

Here is the Source text. I am trying to extract.parse the Name, Email, Birthdat & Phone Number only. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Basic data
</td><td align="left" width="10" style="padding:0; margin:0;"> </td><td align="left" width="290" style="padding:0;"> </td></tr><tr><td align="right" width="250" style="padding-bottom:8px; margin:0; color: #555555; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px;">
Name:
</td><td align="left" width="10" style="padding:0; margin:0;"> </td><td align="left" width="290" style="color: #262626; padding-bottom:8px ; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px;">Test User3</td></tr><tr><td align="right" width="250" style="padding-bottom:8px; margin:0; color: #555555; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px;">
Email:
</td><td align="left" width="10" style="padding:0; margin:0;"> </td><td align="left" width="290" style="color: #262626; padding-bottom:8px ; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px;"><span style="color: #262626; text-decoration:none;">testuser3@busystreet.com</span></td></tr><tr><td align="center" colspan="3" height="20" width="100%" style="color: #262626; padding:0; margin:0; line-height:20px;"> </td></tr><tr><td align="right" width="250" style="padding-bottom:8px; margin:0; color: #002a5c; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px;">
Custom data
</td><td align="left" width="10" style="padding:0; margin:0;"> </td><td align="left" width="290" style="padding:0;"> </td></tr><tr><td align="right" width="250" style="padding-bottom:8px; margin:0; color: #555555; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px;">ref:
</td><td align="left" width="10" style="padding:0; margin:0;"> </td><td align="left" width="290" style="color: #262626; padding-bottom:8px ; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px;">06/16/1963</td></tr><tr><td align="right" width="250" style="padding-bottom:8px; margin:0; color: #555555; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px;">cellphone:
                                                            </td><td align="left" width="10" style="padding:0; margin:0;"> </td><td align="left" width="290" style="color: #262626; padding-bottom:8px ; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px;">6152498588</td></tr><tr><td align="center" colspan="3" height="20" width="100%" style="color: #262626; padding:0; margin:0; line-height:20px;"> </td></tr><tr><td align="right" width="250" style="padding-bottom:8px; margin:0; color: #002a5c; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px;">
```

Thanx in advance,

Doug

Comment: [You really shouldn't try to use regular expressions to parse HTML.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/41071)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead. Parsing HTML with regex is a bad thing, except for very specific cases.

Comment: Thanx. I am using WinAutomation to Automate some tasks and it uses REGEX

Answer (score 0):

Better use SimpleXML instead of regex to parse HTML!